# Do and While Loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In this program, I am suppose to let the user input data, and the program will calculate what they need and show it. I am suppose to use a while,for, and do loop for this program.

- So far I have been successful with the For loop, but I am having a problem with how to use a While and Do loop for this program.
- Can someone give me some advice?

Here are my codes :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float load()
{
    float sal = 0.0;    
    printf("Enter Salary\n");
    scanf("%f", &sal);
    return sal;
}

float calcRate(float s)
{
    if (s > 40000)
        return 4.0;
    if (s >= 30000 && s <= 40000)
        return 5.5;
    if (s < 30000)
        return 7.0;

}
void calcRaise(float sal, float rate, float *raise, float *totraise)
{
    *raise = (sal*rate) / (float)100;
    *totraise = *totraise + *raise;

}
void calcNewSal(float sal, float raise, float *newsal, float *totnewsal)
{
    *newsal = sal + raise;
    *totnewsal = *totnewsal + *newsal;

}
void calcTotSal(float *sal, float *totsal)
{
    *totsal = *totsal + *sal;
}

void print(float sal, float rate, float raise, float newsal, float totnewsal, float totraise, float totsal)
{

    printf("     %0.2f  %0.2f  %0.2f  %0.2f\n", sal,rate,raise,newsal);


}

void main()
{
    float sal = 0.0;
    float rate, raise, newsal;
    float totraise = 0;
    float totnewsal = 0;
    float totsal = 0;
    printf("     Salary  Rate %%  Raise  New Salary\n");


        for (int i=1;i<=7;i++)
        {
        sal = load();
        rate = calcRate(sal);
        calcRaise(sal, rate, &raise, &totraise);
        calcNewSal(sal, raise, &newsal, &totnewsal);
        calcTotSal(&sal, &totsal);

        print(sal, rate, raise, newsal, totsal, totraise, totnewsal);
        fflush(stdin);

        }
    printf("Total: %0.2f %0.2f %0.2f  \n", totsal, totraise, totnewsal);
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Are you asking for someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: @jeff I'm asking for advice.......

Comment: BTW, what is a `While and Do loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the while loop as follows:

```
int i=1;
while(i<=7)  {
    sal = load();
        rate = calcRate(sal);
        calcRaise(sal, rate, &raise, &totraise);
        calcNewSal(sal, raise, &newsal, &totnewsal);
        calcTotSal(&sal, &totsal);

        print(sal, rate, raise, newsal, totsal, totraise, totnewsal);
        fflush(stdin);
        i++;
}
```

And the do-while as follows:

```
int i=1;
do  {
        sal = load();
        rate = calcRate(sal);
        calcRaise(sal, rate, &raise, &totraise);
        calcNewSal(sal, raise, &newsal, &totnewsal);
        calcTotSal(&sal, &totsal);

        print(sal, rate, raise, newsal, totsal, totraise, totnewsal);
        fflush(stdin);
        i++;
} while(i<=7);
```

Both of the above will have the same effect as the for loop you've written. The number of iterations is hardcoded here so there shouldn't be any apparent difference between while & do-while. However, if you initialize i to 8 instead of 1 you will notice that while loop block does not execute at all but the do-while executes once.